# Wiring GFCI/Switch Combo

Tags: electrical

My current set up is that I have a switch on the kitchen wall with power from the panel at the switch.  Then a 12-3 runs to a box under the sink, where there is a half hot for the plugged disposal.  The switched (red wire) feeds the top of the half hot.  The always hot wire (black) from the 12-3 feeds the bottom (always on) of the half hot and also is spliced to a GFCI that is on the end of a kitchen island.  (The sink is in the island.)  (Neutral is also spliced too at the under sink box to connect to the unbroken side of the half hot and the white wire leading to the GFCI.)

So, at the switch box, there's a 12-2 from the service panel, and then leading out there's a 12-3 to the box under the sink.  And then from the under-sink box there's a 12-2 to a current GFCI that I want to replace with USB/duplex.

I want to replace the GFCI in the island with a GFCI-protected outlet that has USB chargers in it.  I can see a couple of ways to do this.  I could probably just put a two-gang box in under the sink and install a GFCI outlet after the half hot and and then put the 12-2 running to the box that will hold the USB on the load from the GFCI.  Then I don't need to touch the switch box.

What I'm wondering though is whether there's a way to put a combo GFCI/Switch device at the switch and then be able to run to a switched outlet (for the disposal) and to feed the USB on the load side.  I've read a bunch of old questions and have read the Leviton instructions for the combo devices and I'm very confused.  I'm ok with the switched receptacle being GFCI, or, as I understand the code, it doesn't need to be for a disposal.

I need help with the wiring both at the switch box and at the box under the sink.  To recap, existing wiring is:  12-2 going into the switch box.  12-3 leaving the switch box and going into the under sink box.  12-2 (housed in FMC if it matters) leaving the under sink box to the box where I would like to put the USB receptacle.

Edit:  Still confused about how to wire using existing wiring with a switch gfci combo and the 3-wire romex leaving the wall box.  A picture of my best guess here with ground wires omitted:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are splitting power to disposal and dishwasher, you cannot "split" and have some things be GFCI and others not.  You have to put the works on GFCI, which will be annoying.

Putting the GFCI under the sink in a 2-gang box is out of the question; the reason is GFCIs must be accessible.   Your options are:

### GFCI breaker. And done.

Or:

### Put the entire downline on the GFCI+recep+switch

...including the switch itself.

Pretty simple to wire:  The hot and neutral from supply go on the LINE terminals. **Nothing else goes on the LINE terminals**.  All other things go on LOAD, no matter what (except grounds, of course).  Pigtail if necessary.

Comment: A GFCI behind a cabinet door would be "accessible" no?

Comment: I think if you have to move the recycle bin, the shelf of cleaning supplies and reach behind the garbage disposal to reset a GFCI, that violates the spirit of "accessible".

Comment: Yeah -- that would be more problematic -- one could position the GFCI box up at the front of the cabinet to avoid this, though.

Comment: Thanks very much.  The box under the sink is on the cabinet wall about 11 inches from the front of the cabinet, so basically right there when I open the door.  I don’t know what the code requires for reasonably accessible Or what an inspector would say, but with respect to real world use it would be much easier than going to the panel.

Comment: Thanks.  Still confused about wiring.  I added a picture of my guess of how to wire.

Comment: @Larry Yeah, that looks fantastic.  The thick wires wires there are the switch leads, which are not terminals at all, but are embedded wires (like a dimmer might have) -- they're not going to LINE (in case anyone else looking at it was wondering).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help -- I don't have sufficient board privileges yet to vote for your answer and have it be public but I really appreciate the help.